# Push notifications from Game Center in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, notifications, push

I'd like to send a notification to players anytime someone on Game Center beats their high score. This is to help keep players playing my game. So if their phones on sleep and someone beats their high score, a message would pop up in their lock screen saying something like "\(user) just beat your high score... beat them now!" I'm using cocos2d, sprite builder and Xcode in swift. I've been searching online for a few hours but I haven't found answers that help my case. Where do I begin? Is what I am trying to accomplish possible?

Also, I found online that I need a server to setup push notifications, what if I don't have one? Is is still possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have a read of the apple developer docs for GameCenter and Gamekit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/